# what is the SLA for Google App script?

Tags: google-apps-script, host, availability

I am new to Google App scripts and I have a few questions (I've done the diligent of going thru the FAQs) that I couldn't find answers yet

1. I read that Google App scripts are hosted in Google Drive. Where does it actually get executed?
2. are there any SLA or availability figures for the Google App scripts hosting environment?
3. can I host the Google App scripts (we will mainly use these as Gadgets for Google Site) on other environment? such as App engine?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anything official that answer these questions. So the following answers are just from my experience of working with Apps Script and as a Top Contributor.

1. It gets executed on Google servers, under the "script" subdomain at google.com. There's no info regarding the infrastructure.
2. There's no SLA. AFAIK it is not even covered in Google support for "Google for Work" (new name of Apps for Business)
3. No, you cannot host it anywhere else. And also not embed it anywhere expect a Google Site.

Comment: thank you. that explains why i couldn't find any info regarding these questions. however, it appears that there's indeed some published SLA for Google for work http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en-GB/terms/sla.html

Comment: Yes, Google for Work has an SLA. But I don't think Apps Script is covered by it, or even supported at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Preface

First of all, Google Apps Script seems to be separate from Google Sheets/Docs/Forms/Drive as noted in [HIPAA Included Functionality](https://web.archive.org/web/20220121175523/https://workspace.google.com/terms/2015/1/hipaa_functionality.html):

> *As of July 21, 2020, The following functionality is Included Functionality under the applicable HIPAA Business Associate Addendum:*
>
> Gmail, Calendar, Drive (including Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Forms), Apps Script, Keep, Sites, Jamboard, Hangouts (chat messaging feature only), Google Chat, Google Meet, Google Voice (managed users only), Google Cloud Search, Cloud Identity Management, Google Groups, Google Tasks and Vault (if applicable).

So, in official docs, Google recognises Apps Script as separate service, as seen in Google Workspace HIPAA Included Functionality terms.

### Is there SLA for Apps Script

There is Google Workspace Service Level Agreement (SLA, which is a matter of question), where Apps Script **is NOT included** in covered services.

From [Google Workspace Service Level Agreement](https://web.archive.org/web/20211123083110/https://workspace.google.com/terms/sla.html):

> Last modified: July 12, 2021
>
> ..
>
> "Google Workspace Covered Services" means the Gmail, Currents, Google Calendar, Google Cloud Print, Google Cloud Search, Google Docs, Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Forms, Google Drive, Google Groups for Business, Google Hangouts messaging and video initiation, Google Chat, Google Meet, Google Keep, Google Sites, Google Jamboard, Google Tasks, Google Vault, and Google Voice components of the Service. This does not include the Gmail Labs functionality, and Google Jamboard Hardware components of the Service.

There is also additional [Google Apps Script Additional Terms](https://web.archive.org/web/20211203031502/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/terms) which have no mention of SLA (as of December 2021).

It's not should be considered any kind of legal advice, but looks like there is no explicit Apps Script SLA.